# writing text to an html file type

Tags: java, file, html

I am trying to write the result of the following method to a webpage. I think it is possible to do, I am just having trouble figuring out exactly how to do it. Any help would be very appreciated. 
Thanks.

```
...
      System.out.println("Final Register");
      for (int i=0; i < ch.length; i++)
        {
         System.out.println(cd.getDenomLiteralAt(i)+" "+cd.getDenomNumAt(i));
        }
   }

...
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to accomplish? What is your context? What type of technology you are using? Web application container? technology used?

Comment: I am making a program to imitate a change drawer. I want to write the contents of the change drawer, once a purchase has been made, to a webpage. I am using bluej to code the functions of the changedrawer, and I want to write the final change draw contents in a table as html in notepad.

Comment: so you are not using any web server. you just need to write to a local file with an html extension?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In java there are many ways to write data on a file. To write text data the easiest way is by using a BufferedWriter.

See demo below

```
FileWriter fWriter = null;
BufferedWriter writer = null;
try {
    fWriter = new FileWriter("fileName.html");
    writer = new BufferedWriter(fWriter);
    writer.write("<span>This iss your html content here</span>");
    writer.newLine(); //this is not actually needed for html files - can make your code more readable though 
    writer.close(); //make sure you close the writer object 
} catch (Exception e) {
  //catch any exceptions here
}
```

Comment: It seems to come up with error "Can not find class FileWriter"

Comment: make an import : import java.io.FileWriter;

Comment: it would be also good to change the title of the question to something like 'writing text to an html file type'

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is know the path to the public HTML file of your webserver.

Run the Java code and write to a file below that path. It's no different than writing to any other file on a machine, except this one the world can see. Only thing is, if your Java will be creating the file, you should be sure to set protective enough permissions for the file. 0755 is moderately safe.